# Iphone test automation - Need Software

Tags: mobile, automation, qtp

In my work we recently started to build iphone (and a little bit of android) apps.

and now we are searching for a software that we could make an automated tests for our apps.
It could be a virtual emulator or a physical device, it doesn't matter.
the only condition is that we can't use a jailbroken devices.

Can someone help me to find some softwares so we could make automation on iphone (and android if possible)?

If there are emulators or plugins for QTP it will also be fine Because we are using QTP Regularly.

Thanks a lot,
Idan.

Answer (score 1):

You can test mobile devices with QTP using [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/mobilecloud_qtp.html), I'm not sure how good a fix this will be for you since they provide the mobile devices as a service.